# Pushing values to getColumn.values for Excel add In

Tags: javascript, json, excel

So I am trying to import and read a json to an excel sheet, using an add-in I'm developing. So I've gotten to a point where I'm getting `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` from my new `worksheet`. Then I'm trying to push the json fields onto the `Range.values` arrays of the columns. However once I run the program the worksheet is still blank. Here is the code:

```
function importJson(json, name){
Excel.run(function (context) {
  ...
    var sheetRange = newWorksheet.getRange("A1:B1");
                            sheetRange.load('values');
                            var aColumn = sheetRange.getColumn(0);
                            var bColumn = sheetRange.getColumn(1);
                            aColumn.load('values');
                            bColumn.load('values');
                            return context.sync().then(function () {                             
                                printJson(json, aColumn, bColumn);

                            });
});

printJson(json, aColumn, bColumn)
{
 if (json instanceof Object) {                                
                    aColumn.values.push(json.display);                    
                    if (json.default != null) {
                        bColumn.values.push(json.default);                    
                    }                   
                }                
                if (json.fields != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.fields.length; i++) {
                        printSchema(json.fields[i], aColumn, bColumn);
                    }
                }
}
```

Running the debugger I see the values from the `json` object being pushed onto the arrays but run I still don't see them on the `worksheet`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the js API, but calling (e.g.) `bColumn.values` just fetches all of the values from the range into an array - updating that array does not update the source range.  You would need to write the updated values back to the sheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams I see, so I would have to do something like return aColumn and bColumn from the printSchema and update the sheets.values from them?

Comment: Yes but you'd want to do that at the very end of the process, otherwise you're reading and writing a whole columns of data each time through the loop, just to update one or two cells

Comment: @TimWilliams. Thank you for your help! I got it to work like a charm, and added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Thanks to a little nudge from @TimWilliams, it was realized that I wasn't updating the *worksheets* values within my `printJson` method. So once I pushed all of the values I wanted in Column A and Column B I added this step in my last `return sync().then(function(){})`....

```
    Excel.run(function (context) {
  ...
    var sheetRange = newWorksheet.getRange("A1:B1");
                            sheetRange.load('values');
                            var aColumn = sheetRange.getColumn(0);
                            var bColumn = sheetRange.getColumn(1);
                            aColumn.load('values');
                            bColumn.load('values');
                            return context.sync().then(function () {                             
                                printJson(json, aColumn, bColumn);
                                ****
                                for (var i = 1; i < aColumn.values.length + 2; i++)
                                {
                                 var aColumnSheet = newWorksheet.getRange("A" + i);
                                 aColumnSheet.values = aColumn.values[i];                                                              
                                 }


                                 for (var i = 1; i < bColumn.values.length + 2; i++) {
                                 var bColumnSheet = newWorksheet.getRange("B" + i);
                                 bColumnSheet.values = bColumn.values[i];
                                 }

                               *****
                                });
    });
```

Gives me two beautiful columns of data in Column A and Column B. Thanks again @TimWilliams!